# R convert factor in format "1/15/2016 3:20:00 AM" to Date

Tags: r, date, time, type-conversion

Input is in the format

> "1/15/2016  3:20:00 AM"

```
mydate<- factor("1/15/2016  3:20:00 AM")
```

I tried many codes such as

```
mydate<-as.Date(mydate, format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
```

but getting NA values as output,
Please help!

Comment: If it is really your format, you misses a space. But I don't see the point of `factor`.

Comment: If you just want the date, you probably could just do `as.Date(mydate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`. Otherwise, I don't understand why are you using the `as.Date` function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has both a date and a time component. I would first parse the full date and time to a [POSIXct](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) value, and then, if you're really only interested in the date part, you can coerce to [Date](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Dates.html):

```
dtstr <- '1/15/2016  3:20:00 AM';
dt <- as.POSIXct(dstr,format='%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p');
dt;
## [1] "2016-01-15 03:20:00 EST"
date <- as.Date(dt);
date;
## [1] "2016-01-15"
```

Comment: Just a quick note but you don't need all the semicolons

Comment: Thanks @bgoldst it works but what if i want to use a loop and convert a no of '1/15/2016  3:20:00 AM' to dates

Comment: Why you use use a loop? Can't you just run this line as is?

Comment: @Laterow See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004672/using-user-defined-for-loop-function-to-construct-a-data-frame/29004774#29004774 for my go-to reply when someone questions my use of semicolons in R.

Comment: @VarunDey The code should work on a vector of dt strings as-is, returning a vector of POSIXct or Date objects.