# Another way to indicate variable from a given data frame?

Tags: r

My question seems to be easy but difficult to describe, see the code below. Let's create a data frame first:

```
Length<-c(10,11,9,8,10)
Width<-c(5,5.4,4.7,5.6,6.1)
Layer<-c(8,10,12,10,14) 
data<-data.frame(Length, Width, Layer)
data
    Length Width Layer
1     10   5.0     8
2     11   5.4    10
3      9   4.7    12
4      8   5.6    10
5     10   6.1    14
```

And as we all know, if we'd like to indicate variable from a given data frame, we need to type as below:

```
data$Layer
[1]  8 10 12 10 14
```

However, when there are many variables it becomes time consuming so I'd like to find other ways:

```
var_list<-c("Length", "Width", "Layer")
var_list
[1] "Length" "Width"  "Layer" 
> var_list[1]
[1] "Length"
> var_list[2]
[1] "Width"
> var_list[3]
[1] "Layer"
```

So a variable list is created, and I'd like to use this to indicate to the data set but in vain:

```
> data$var_list
  NULL
> data$var_list[1]
  NULL
> data$var_list[2]
  NULL
> data$var_list[3]
  NULL
```

Hope my description is clear enough and thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Use `data[[var_list[1]]]`, etc for individuals, or `data[var_list]` for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: you can get the names of the columns via the `names()` function:

```
names(data);
## [1] "Length" "Width"  "Layer"
```

2: You can extract a single column using the `` `[[`() `` operation:

```
data[['Layer']];
## [1]  8 10 12 10 14
data[[names(data)[3L]]];
## [1]  8 10 12 10 14
```

3: But since you end up using a numeric index into the vector of names anyway, I suggest you simply use numeric indexing on the original data.frame:

```
data[[3L]];
## [1]  8 10 12 10 14
```

Comment: You don't need to use semicolons at the eol in R

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004672/using-user-defined-for-loop-function-to-construct-a-data-frame/29004774#29004774 for my go-to reply when someone questions my use of semicolons in R.

Comment: Okay, suit yourself :)  I figured there had to be a reason