# Assign vector to longer vector by group

Tags: r, match, assign

I've been struggling to assign values to some groups in some data, but I am somewhat stuck. I've tried `match`ing `unique`'s and `rep` and other. I hope someone here can help me.

I have a data set that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
GRP.id  = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
group  = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
> df
  GRP.id group
1      1     A
2      2     B
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      3     C
6      3     C
```

and a vector with some values that need to be assign to each group

```
value <- c(.3, .8, .3)
```

such that I get this result

```
  GRP.id group value
1      1     A   0.3
2      2     B   0.8
3      2     B   0.8
4      2     B   0.8
5      3     C   0.3
6      3     C   0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$value <- value[match(df$GRP.id,unique(df$GRP.id))];
df;
##   GRP.id group value
## 1      1     A   0.3
## 2      2     B   0.8
## 3      2     B   0.8
## 4      2     B   0.8
## 5      3     C   0.3
## 6      3     C   0.3
```

If you know for a fact that the `df$GRP.id` column will always consist of `1:n` for some max `n`, then you can replace the `match(df$GRP.id,unique(df$GRP.id))` piece with just `df$GRP.id`. But for robustness (i.e. just in case that assumption will not always be true) I'd go with the `match()`/`unique()` design.

Comment: Very beautiful response. Thank you for the added comment about robustness. Can I ask why do you end your lines with a `;`?

Comment: @EricFail Thanks :) See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29004774/4272464 for my standard response about semicolons.